# Does PHP ala FCGI use the IIS-AppPool or the FCGI AppPool on IIS6

Tags: php, iis-6, web-applications, fcgi

I've got an IIS6 (win2k3 server) setup using PHP via FCGI (microsofts install this time); and I know FCGI has its own Application pool of sorts; I was wondering therefore if this means that the PHP is isolated from the IIS AppPool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [this](http://www.iis.net/download/fastcgi) answers your question.

> CGI programs are executables launched by the web server for each
>   request in order to process the
>   request and generate dynamic responses
>   that are sent back to the client. CGI
>   has poor performance due to the high
>   cost of starting and shutting down a
>   process for each request. FastCGI
>   addresses the performance issues
>   inherent to CGI by providing a
>   mechanism to reuse a single process
>   over and over again for many requests

**FEATURE**

> Configurable maximum number of FastCGI
>   processes per application pool

Comment: But is that per FastCGI application pool; or IIS App Pool?

Comment: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/248/configure-the-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60/

Comment: IIS creates an appPool for the web site and a CGI application will run under it's own process. So basically with FastCGI, the same CGI process will be used again n again instead of creating a new process everytime.